# Field 'role' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel

I tried looking for solution for this problem in stackoverflow and I found the same question. However, after following the solution, it still didn't solve my problem. I know by using  *protected guarded = []* or use *nullable* at the database will solve the problem. However I don't think that it is a good practice or encourage clean code..not in my situation. Here I include my code. Please help

users table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('staff_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('department')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('role');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->foreignId('current_team_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('profile_photo_path', 2048)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

user model

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'role',
    ];
```

fortify create new user controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Actions\Fortify;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\CreatesNewUsers;
use Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream;

class CreateNewUser implements CreatesNewUsers
{
    use PasswordValidationRules;

    /**
     * Validate and create a newly registered user.
     *
     * @param  array  $input
     * @return \App\Models\User
     */
    public function create(array $input)
    {
        Validator::make($input, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
            'terms' => Jetstream::hasTermsAndPrivacyPolicyFeature() ? ['accepted', 'required'] : '',
        ])->validate();

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $input['name'],
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
        ]);

        $user->role = 'user';
        return $user;
    }
```

}

user controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $user = User::get();
        return view('users.index', compact('user'));
    }
}
```

Comment: You're calling `User::create()`, but not supplying a `'role' => ...`. That column doesn't allow `null`, and doesn't have a default value so you need to provide one.

Comment: $user->role = 'user'; $user->save(); or  $user = User::create([
            'name' => $input['name'],
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
            'role' => 'user'
        ]);

Comment: You have `$user->role = 'user'` _after_ the `::create()` call, but that should be inside of the call, like `$user = User::create(['name' => $input['name'], 'email' => $input['email'], 'password' => Hash::make($input['password']), 'role' => 'user']);`

Comment: @TimLewis i just add a 'role' => $input['role'] and now the error is saying Undefined array key "role"

Comment: @jabs93 Does your `$input` array have a `'role'` index? Your error is saying that it does not. Hence why you used `'user'` as the hard-coded value.

Comment: @RamilHuseynov Just a heads up, `$user->role = 'user'; $user->save();` won't work here. The error is triggered when `User::create()` is called, and that subsequent code is not hit. To use `->save()`, it would need to be `$user = new User();`, then `$user->name = ...`, (same with `$user->email = ...`, `$user->password = ...;`), then `$user->role = 'user';` and finally `$user->save();`